# How to write a summation from 1 to n in r

Tags: r

So I basically want to be able to write out the sum of a function from k=1 to n (n being undefined right now)

I have written

```
sum((((-1)^k-1)/factorial(2*k-1))*x^2*k-1)
```

However how to I get it to where it has sigma from 1 to 5 for example?

Comment: If `n=10` then `sum(sapply(1:10,function(k)(((-1)^k-1)/factorial(2*k-1))*k^2*k-1))`  . I changed `x` by `k` since I think it is a typo...

Comment: Thanks u so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function like below

```
f <- function(x,n) sum((-1)^(seq(n)-1)/factorial(2*seq(n)-1)*x^(2*seq(n)-1))
```

such that

```
> f(pi/4,10)
[1] 0.7071068

> f(pi/4,5)
[1] 0.7071068

> f(pi/4,2)
[1] 0.7046527
```

---

Note that when `k` goes to the infinity (or a sufficiently large number), the function `f` can be treated as `sin(x)` since this is the Taylor's series of `sin(x)`

```
> f(pi/4,20)
[1] 0.7071068

> f(pi/4,10)
[1] 0.7071068

> sin(pi/4)
[1] 0.7071068
```

Comment: Thanks u so much, im going to try this out!